# Cluster Google Maps Marker after pulling coordinates from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, html, google-maps-api-3

What I basically have is a Map that displays simple Google markers.

The Location of the markers is stored in a MySQL database. Now I want to use MarkerCluster to get things organized. However, I am having trouble. Although the guidelines seem fine ( http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/docs/examples.html ) I really can't get it to work.

Currently my markers are defined as:

```
// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
    GDownloadUrl("gen.php", function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now in the example for MarkerCluster I am supposed to define my markers like this:

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  var latlng = new GLatLng(data.photos[i].latitude, data.photos[i].longitude);
  var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
  markers.push(marker);
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

However I have no idea how to combine these two. Markers is already defined and I do not see how markerCluster is being called nor do I understand how I get the data into the markers in the example.

Any pointer appreciated.
Thanks.

George

Answer (score 0):

```
// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
GDownloadUrl("gen.php", function(data) {
  var xml = GXml.parse(data);
  var clusteredmarkers = [];
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type);
    clusteredmarkers.push(marker);
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map,clusteredmarkers);//this also add the cluster to the map
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I only get an empty map. No markers and most importantly no clusters. :-/

Comment: Do I need anything fancy to get this going? The map with the markers works, the clustered stuff I can't see. Could somebody maybe post a complete page that works for him/her, so I can take a look and see what is going wrong with mine? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thanks. However, I ended up porting everything to v3.
"If you do it, do it right."

Thanks, for reading!